# Apply xml script of VQmod only when some condition satisfies opencart

Tags: xml, opencart2.x, vqmod

How can i create a module which only enables only when some values in config match. This module is completely handled by VQmod. And i want to make sure that xml only executes when some value satisfies. Like `if($this->config->get('moduleserial')=='somevalue')` then only my xml should execute. Please guide me in right way.

Comment: I don't know if such a thing is possible, but if it is not, try this in your VQMOD file: ***(1)*** at index.php, define some constant with a value of **1** or **0** based on the condition you are checking (`if(condition o.k) define ('PROCEED_WITH_VQMOD','1') else define ('PROCEED_WITH_VQMOD','0')`...) , ***(2)*** for every change you make, surround your code block with a condniton that checks whether that constant `PROCEED_WITH_VQMOD` is 1

Comment: Are you making changes in single file via vQmod or multiple ?

Comment: I'm trying to change multiple files

Comment: if am little bit confused, you are saying one module (which is handled by xml) is depend on same values of config means already installed other mod/ shipping or any other ext., is Opencart module or you are reffering your code which you want to add by xml is module ? I have few solution in mind but clear this first.

Comment: @user5419232 it was an opencart module and works only with an xml.